Installation issues for CUDA 12.0.1 on a Ubuntu 22.04 Dual Boot
This might get a bit long but I want to make sure I include as much info on what I did as possible.
I’m trying to install CUDA 12.0.1 on a Ubuntu 22.04 Dual Boot.
I don’t know if it’ll be relevant, but my hardware is an Intel i7-13700 2.10GHz processor and a Nvidia GeForce RTX 4070ti. This was first a 100% Windows computer on which I added a Ubuntu boot.
The first issues I have (it might be related to my actual issue so I'm mentioning it) is that my Ubuntu has troubles on boot. After a loading screen, I had the following lines and then a black screen :
[0.186912] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.RP21.PXSX.TURP], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dswload2-326)
[0.186920] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230331/psobject-220)
[0.186922] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.RP21. PXSX.TBDU], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dswload2-326)
[0.186924] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230331/psobject-220)
[1.182055] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2
[1.182140] DMAR: [DMA Write NO_PASID] Request device [05:00.0] fault addr 0x5a5e2000 [fault reason 0x05] PTE Write access is not set
[3.209880] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2
[3.209945] DMAR: [DMA Write NO_PASID] Request device [05:00.0] fault addr 0x5a5e2000 [fault reason 0x05] PTE Write access is not set
[5.225890] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2
[5.225956] DMAR: [DMA Write NO_PASID] Request device [05:00.0] fault addr 0x5a5e2000 [fault reason 0x05] PTE Write access is not set
[7.241950] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2
[7.242015] DMAR: [DMA Write NO_PASID] Request device [05:00.0] fault addr 0x5a5e2000 [fault reason 0x05] PTE Write access is not set
[9.257883] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2
[9.257943] DMAR: [DMA Write NO_PASID] Request device [05:00.0] fault addr 0x5a5e2000 [fault reason 0x05] PTE Write access is not set
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, 219393/12804096 files, 4037540/51200000 blocks
[12.030262] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: unknown chipset (194000a1)
[12.296899] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x00000004A) is beyond end of object (length 0x4A) (20230331/exoparg2-393)
[12.296925] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.CNVW.WGDS due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20230331/psparse-529)
[12.304496] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[12.916304] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[13.746677] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02

After some online searches, the fix was using recovery mode to install nvidia drivers:
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535  
sudo reboot

Now, while the lines still show up, at least I don’t get a black screen and I’m able to log in.
The big issue I have is installing CUDA 12.0.1. Whatever I try, I can't get the installation to run smoothly, even though I’m following the steps from the official installation guide (https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/12.0.1/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html).
1 - Checking CUDA compatibility:
 ~$ sudo update-pciids
    --2024-07-11 17:43:49--  https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/v2.2/pci.ids.bz2
    Resolving pci-ids.ucw.cz (pci-ids.ucw.cz)... 2001:718:1e03:810::f2, 2001:1488:ffff::99, 2a00:da80:fff0:2::3, ...
    Connecting to pci-ids.ucw.cz (pci-ids.ucw.cz)|2001:718:1e03:810::f2|:443... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
    Length: 314472 (307K) [application/octet-stream]
    Saving to: ‘/usr/share/misc/pci.ids.new’
    
    /usr/share/misc/pci 100%[===================>] 307.10K   261KB/s    in 1.2s    
    
    2024-07-11 17:43:54 (261 KB/s) - ‘/usr/share/misc/pci.ids.new’ saved [314472/314472]
    
    Done.
    ~$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation AD104 [GeForce RTX 4070 Ti] (rev a1)
    01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation AD104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)

2 - Checking Linux version
~$ uname -m && cat /etc/*release
x86_64
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

3 - Checking GCC
dymon@dymon-HP-ENVY-Desktop-TE02-1xxx:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

4 - Installing Kernel Headers and Development Packages
~$ uname -r
6.5.0-41-generic
~$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-6.5.0-41-generic is already the newest version (6.5.0-41.41~22.04.2).
linux-headers-6.5.0-41-generic set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libwpe-1.0-1 libwpebackend-fdo-1.0-1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

After the pre-installation steps, I follow the guide of the .deb install (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-12-0-1-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=22.04&target_type=deb_local)
At first everything seems to run smoothly
~$ wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2204.pin
--2024-07-11 17:49:31--  https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2204.pin
Resolving developer.download.nvidia.com (developer.download.nvidia.com)... 152.199.39.144
Connecting to developer.download.nvidia.com (developer.download.nvidia.com)|152.199.39.144|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 190 [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘cuda-ubuntu2204.pin’

cuda-ubuntu2204.pin           100%[==============================================>]     190  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2024-07-11 17:49:31 (4.35 MB/s) - ‘cuda-ubuntu2204.pin’ saved [190/190]
~$ sudo mv cuda-ubuntu2204.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
~$ wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.0.1/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local_12.0.1-525.85.12-1_amd64.deb
--2024-07-11 17:50:45--  https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.0.1/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local_12.0.1-525.85.12-1_amd64.deb
Resolving developer.download.nvidia.com (developer.download.nvidia.com)... 152.199.39.144
Connecting to developer.download.nvidia.com (developer.download.nvidia.com)|152.199.39.144|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3101162268 (2.9G) [application/x-deb]
Saving to: ‘cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local_12.0.1-525.85.12-1_amd64.deb’

cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-loc 100%[==============================================>]   2.89G  40.1MB/s    in 76s     

2024-07-11 17:52:01 (39.2 MB/s) - ‘cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local_12.0.1-525.85.12-1_amd64.deb’ saved [3101162268/3101162268]

~$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local_12.0.1-525.85.12-1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local.
(Reading database ... 207905 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local_12.0.1-525.85.12-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local (12.0.1-525.85.12-1) ...
Setting up cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local (12.0.1-525.85.12-1) ...

The public cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local GPG key does not appear to be installed.
To install the key, run this command:
sudo cp /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local/cuda-C9F1F397-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
~$ sudo cp /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local/cuda-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local  InRelease [1,575 B]
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local  InRelease [1,575 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local  Packages [34.4 kB]
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                             
Hit:5 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                     
Hit:6 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                  
Hit:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done

But when I run sudo apt-get -y install cuda, after all the unpacking happens without any apparent issues, I get the following :
A modprobe blacklist file has been created at /etc/modprobe.d to prevent Nouveau
from loading. This can be reverted by deleting the following file:
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf

A new initrd image has also been created. To revert, please regenerate your
initrd by running the following command after deleting the modprobe.d file:
`/usr/sbin/initramfs -u`

*****************************************************************************
*** Reboot your computer and verify that the NVIDIA graphics driver can   ***
*** be loaded.                                                            ***
*****************************************************************************

INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
Loading new nvidia-525.85.12 DKMS files...
Building for 6.5.0-41-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 6.5.0-41-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-41-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.85.12/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-525 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-525 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up cuda-command-line-tools-12-0 (12.0.1-1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-encode-525:amd64 (525.85.12-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-encode-525:i386 (525.85.12-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libegl1:i386 (1.4.0-1) ...
Setting up libnpp-dev-12-0 (12.0.1.104-1) ...
Setting up cuda-opencl-12-0 (12.0.140-1) ...
Setting up libnvjitlink-dev-12-0 (12.0.140-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-drivers-525:
 cuda-drivers-525 depends on nvidia-dkms-525 (>= 525.85.12); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-525 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-drivers-525 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up cuda-libraries-12-0 (12.0.1-1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Setting up libcurand-dev-12-0 (10.3.1.124-1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-gl-525:i386 (525.85.12-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libcusparse-dev-12-0 (12.0.1.140-1) ...
Setting up libcublas-dev-12-0 (12.0.2.224-1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvcc-12-0 (12.0.140-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-525:
 nvidia-driver-525 depends on nvidia-dkms-525 (= 525.85.12-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-525 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-525 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-drivers:
 cuda-drivers depends on cuda-drivers-525 (= 525.85.12-1); however:
  Package cuda-drivers-525 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-drivers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up cuda-opencl-dev-12-0 (12.0.140-1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                                                        Setting up cuda-compiler-12-0 (12.0.1-1) ...
Setting up cuda-libraries-dev-12-0 (12.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-runtime-12-0:
 cuda-runtime-12-0 depends on cuda-drivers (>= 525.85.12); however:
  Package cuda-drivers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-runtime-12-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-12-0:
 cuda-12-0 depends on cuda-runtime-12-0 (>= 12.0.1); however:
  Package cuda-runtime-12-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-12-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-demo-suite-12-0:
 cuda-demo-suite-12-0 depends on cuda-runtime-12-0; however:
  Package cuda-runtime-12-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-demo-suite-12-0 (--configure):
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda:
 cuda depends on cuda-12-0 (>= 12.0.1); however:
  Package cuda-12-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up default-jre-headless (2:1.11-72build2) ...
Setting up openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 (11.0.23+9-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jjs to provide /usr/bin/jjs (jjs) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool to provide /usr/bin/keytool (keytool) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmid to provide /usr/bin/rmid (rmid) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmiregistry to provide /usr/bin/rmiregistry (rmiregistry) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/pack200 to provide /usr/bin/pack200 (pack200) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/unpack200 to provide /usr/bin/unpack200 (unpack200) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/jexec to provide /usr/bin/jexec (jexec) in auto mode
Setting up openjdk-11-jre:amd64 (11.0.23+9-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) ...
Setting up default-jre (2:1.11-72build2) ...
Setting up cuda-nsight-12-0 (12.0.140-1) ...
Setting up ca-certificates-java (20190909ubuntu1.2) ...
head: cannot open '/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts' for reading: No such file or directory
Adding debian:GlobalSign_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Baltimore_CyberTrust_Root.pem
Adding debian:CFCA_EV_ROOT.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R3.pem
Adding debian:Entrust.net_Premium_2048_Secure_Server_CA.pem
Adding debian:SSL.com_EV_Root_Certification_Authority_ECC.pem
Adding debian:NAVER_Global_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:SSL.com_Root_Certification_Authority_ECC.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_3.pem
Adding debian:OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GC_CA.pem
Adding debian:SwissSign_Silver_CA_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:TUBITAK_Kamu_SM_SSL_Kok_Sertifikasi_-_Surum_1.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_2.pem
Adding debian:HARICA_TLS_ECC_Root_CA_2021.pem
Adding debian:ePKI_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:certSIGN_ROOT_CA.pem
Adding debian:TeliaSonera_Root_CA_v1.pem
Adding debian:Security_Communication_ECC_RootCA1.pem
Adding debian:Certum_Trusted_Network_CA_2.pem
Adding debian:Certainly_Root_R1.pem
Adding debian:Atos_TrustedRoot_2011.pem
Adding debian:AC_RAIZ_FNMT-RCM_SERVIDORES_SEGUROS.pem
Adding debian:Trustwave_Global_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Global_Root_G2.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_3_G3.pem
Adding debian:Buypass_Class_3_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:emSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_C3.pem
Adding debian:E-Tugra_Global_Root_CA_RSA_v3.pem
Adding debian:AffirmTrust_Networking.pem
Adding debian:TWCA_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_TLS_RSA4096_Root_G5.pem
Adding debian:TWCA_Global_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:USERTrust_RSA_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:Telia_Root_CA_v2.pem
Adding debian:Hongkong_Post_Root_CA_1.pem
Adding debian:Security_Communication_RootCA2.pem
Adding debian:E-Tugra_Global_Root_CA_ECC_v3.pem
Adding debian:T-TeleSec_GlobalRoot_Class_2.pem
Adding debian:Starfield_Services_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_R4.pem
Adding debian:Buypass_Class_2_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Global_Root_G3.pem
Adding debian:SwissSign_Gold_CA_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:GTS_Root_R2.pem
Adding debian:Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority_-_EC1.pem
Adding debian:Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_ECC_RootCA_2015.pem
Adding debian:SSL.com_EV_Root_Certification_Authority_RSA_R2.pem
Adding debian:GTS_Root_R3.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_G2.pem
Adding debian:TunTrust_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:UCA_Extended_Validation_Root.pem
Adding debian:Amazon_Root_CA_2.pem
Adding debian:Certum_Trusted_Network_CA.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_G3.pem
Adding debian:ACCVRAIZ1.pem
Adding debian:SecureTrust_CA.pem
Adding debian:D-TRUST_BR_Root_CA_1_2020.pem
Adding debian:Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority_-_G4.pem
Adding debian:Secure_Global_CA.pem
Adding debian:COMODO_RSA_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_R5.pem
Adding debian:Izenpe.com.pem
Adding debian:AffirmTrust_Premium.pem
Adding debian:certSIGN_Root_CA_G2.pem
Adding debian:HiPKI_Root_CA_-_G1.pem
Adding debian:Go_Daddy_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:SecureSign_RootCA11.pem
Adding debian:E-Tugra_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:Autoridad_de_Certificacion_Firmaprofesional_CIF_A62634068_2.pem
Adding debian:Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_RootCA_2015.pem
Adding debian:Security_Communication_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:ANF_Secure_Server_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Amazon_Root_CA_4.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_Root_E46.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_1_G3.pem
Adding debian:Microsoft_ECC_Root_Certificate_Authority_2017.pem
Adding debian:OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GB_CA.pem
Adding debian:NetLock_Arany_=Class_Gold=_Főtanúsítvány.pem
Adding debian:GTS_Root_R4.pem
Adding debian:AffirmTrust_Commercial.pem
Adding debian:Trustwave_Global_ECC_P384_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.pem
Adding debian:Amazon_Root_CA_1.pem
Adding debian:HARICA_TLS_RSA_Root_CA_2021.pem
Adding debian:UCA_Global_G2_Root.pem
Adding debian:GDCA_TrustAUTH_R5_ROOT.pem
Adding debian:Security_Communication_RootCA3.pem
Adding debian:e-Szigno_Root_CA_2017.pem
Adding debian:ISRG_Root_X1.pem
Adding debian:Autoridad_de_Certificacion_Firmaprofesional_CIF_A62634068.pem
Adding debian:AC_RAIZ_FNMT-RCM.pem
Adding debian:SZAFIR_ROOT_CA2.pem
Adding debian:Certainly_Root_E1.pem
Adding debian:Amazon_Root_CA_3.pem
Adding debian:Certigna.pem
Adding debian:emSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_G3.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Trusted_Root_G4.pem
Adding debian:USERTrust_ECC_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:vTrus_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Microsec_e-Szigno_Root_CA_2009.pem
Adding debian:Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:Trustwave_Global_ECC_P256_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Certigna_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:CA_Disig_Root_R2.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_High_Assurance_EV_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Certum_Trusted_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:D-TRUST_EV_Root_CA_1_2020.pem
Adding debian:XRamp_Global_CA_Root.pem
Adding debian:emSign_Root_CA_-_C1.pem
Adding debian:ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
Adding debian:IdenTrust_Commercial_Root_CA_1.pem
Adding debian:GLOBALTRUST_2020.pem
Adding debian:GTS_Root_R1.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Global_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Comodo_AAA_Services_root.pem
Adding debian:Actalis_Authentication_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:T-TeleSec_GlobalRoot_Class_3.pem
Adding debian:ISRG_Root_X2.pem
Adding debian:Microsoft_RSA_Root_Certificate_Authority_2017.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_Root_R46.pem
Adding debian:Certum_EC-384_CA.pem
Adding debian:emSign_Root_CA_-_G1.pem
Adding debian:SSL.com_Root_Certification_Authority_RSA.pem
Adding debian:Starfield_Class_2_CA.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R6.pem
Adding debian:COMODO_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_TLS_ECC_P384_Root_G5.pem
Adding debian:AffirmTrust_Premium_ECC.pem
Adding debian:D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_EV_2009.pem
Adding debian:vTrus_ECC_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Starfield_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_2009.pem
Adding debian:COMODO_ECC_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_2_G3.pem
Adding debian:Hongkong_Post_Root_CA_3.pem
Adding debian:IdenTrust_Public_Sector_Root_CA_1.pem
done.
Setting up cuda-nvvp-12-0 (12.0.146-1) ...
Setting up cuda-visual-tools-12-0 (12.0.1-1) ...
Setting up cuda-tools-12-0 (12.0.1-1) ...
Setting up cuda-toolkit-12-0 (12.0.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20230311ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

done.
done.
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.13.1-4.2ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-41-generic
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.8) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-525
 cuda-drivers-525
 nvidia-driver-525
 cuda-drivers
 cuda-runtime-12-0
 cuda-12-0
 cuda-demo-suite-12-0
 cuda
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

From the little I understand, the issue might be related to the nvidia drivers, but I made sure that both nvidia-dkms-525 and nvidia-drivers-525 were installed. (I can't post the /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.85.12/build/make.log because of characters limitations)
I tried browsing askubuntu for answers but nothing I tried worked. I also tried re-installing Ubuntu, using the .run instead of .deb and installing on an older Ubuntu version (20.04) but nothing worked and I'm out of ideas. If somebody could give me a nudge in the right direction it would really help me a lot.
Thank you.

Did you Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.85.12/build/make.log as suggested? Can you [edit] your question to include it (or at least the most relevant parts of it)

Yes I checked it but unfortunately there is so many warning and errors in this file that I can't understand what is causig the issue. I initially tried adding it to my post but its way too long to fit within the character limitations.
However the lines including the word "error" are either :

too many arguments given for function get_user_pages
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:251: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.85.12/build/nvidia/XXXXXX.o] Error 1 (where XXXXXX is one of 6 files)
assignment of read-only member ‘vm_flags’

I hope this gives you more insight

Your new hardware prob needs 24.04 with the 6.8 kernel and the Nvidia 555 driver from graphics-drivers ppa.CUDA is just an app. Use the.run script to reject Nvidia drivers and script options to override sys first with cuda-12.1/bin and cuda-12.1/lib. Don't run as root, take ownership of /use/local before running. There are answers here for doing this.

Hey @ubfan1
Thank you so much, it worked perfectly for me !
